# Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' Operation failed with exitcode 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have looked through my code for a very long time and cannot figure out why I am getting the error:

> ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 3: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
>   Operation failed with exitcode 1

```
insert into Employees values (1, 'Jerald', 'Wright', '300  Stanton Dr', '102939489102', 5);
insert into Employees values (2, 'Janey', 'Gries', '300 Stanton Dr', '130492847281', 5);
insert into Employees values (3, 'Ashley', 'Jackson', '3009 Woodland St', '102938192093', 5);
insert into Employees values (4, 'Paul', 'Blart', '9980 Campus Ave', '18927345867', 5);
insert into Employees values (5, 'Brandon', 'Flowers', '451 Sunset Dr', '12103948192', 6);
insert into Employees values (6, 'Jenny', 'Frank', '313 Lynn Ave', '13102929304', 6);
```

This code insert is going into my table:

```
create table Employees(
  EmployeeID int not null,
  FirstName varchar(255),
  LastName varchar(255),
  address varchar(255),
  phoneNO varchar(11),
  ManagerID int not null,
  primary key (EmployeeID)
);
```

Comment: Are you sure that Employees is empty?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I haven't added any data to employees until running this

Comment: @Cal, you can check by select query - like select * from employee

Comment: You should make `EmployeeID int not null,` have a `AUTO_INCREMENT` option.. And drop the EmployeeID  from the INSERT values.. Besides you are misusing MySQL insert feature you should be using ANSi INSERT SQL instead like this `insert into Employees (<columns>)  values (<values>)`

Comment: @RaymondNijland my teacher told us to use this format

Comment: "my teacher told us to use this format " Your teacher should study again then..the format `insert into Employees values (1, 'Jerald', 'Wright', '300  Stanton Dr', '102939489102', 5);` is prone to errors imagine if you change the existing column order in the table like this `create table Employees(
  EmployeeID int not null,

  LastName varchar(255),   FirstName varchar(255),
  address varchar(255),
  phoneNO varchar(11),
  ManagerID int not null,
  primary key (EmployeeID)
);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after executing your query I found it shows phoneno field datalength is short, when I make it varchar(30) it work properly
You can check in below link

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a74110